# How do I get Visual Studio 2010 to pass a variable to MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have built a custom msbuild deploy.targets file that allows me to publish the resulting binaries to a directory that I specify on the command line.  What that means is that if I run

$>msbuild /p:DestServer=\myserver\final-dest

then my project will be compiled, and the resulting *.dlls will be copied to a staging instance - in this case the directory final-dest on myserver.  I want this functionality because when I do a compile for good, I want a copy of the *.dlls in that directory, but I also want them local.

Here's my issue - I'd really like to not have to issue that from the command line. When I choose the Release Build Configuration (Project | Properties | Build), I'd like to be able to specify the /p:DestServer=\myserver\final-dest as an argument that msbuild would use *as it does its normal build*.

Where do I specify this?

In Project Properties | Build Events, I could specify pre-build or post-build events - but isn't this "part of the build" events?

Ideally, if someone could give me the menu sequence in Visual Studio 2010, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to edit project files - there is another solution.

Each *.csproj file contains this: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />`.

On my pc and .Net 4.0 this file is located in `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"`

Add new `PropertyGroup` inside `Project` like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
 <PropertyGroup>  
    <DestServer>\myserver\final-dest</DestServer>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
<!-- a lot of stuff -->
...
</Project>
```

All your builds now (either from MSBuild and Visual Studio) will use this property, so you don't need to modify .csproj or to pass args from Command Line

**Update**

That was a quick-and-dirty way to go, since it will override all projects building on that PC. *Only do this, if there are a lot of projects and you have no permissions to modify them*

Normally you just add a new `PropertyGroup` inside single project.

If there are a lot of projects, where you need this variable, you can create and import your custom extension targets *bellow* default targets:

> App1.csproj

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\myCustom.targets" />
...
</Project>
```

and

> myCustom.targets

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>  
    <DestServer>\myserver\final-dest</DestServer>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: So the variable is not in source control, not even in the source tree, and applies to every single project built on this machine? Not a good idea IMO, maybe OK as a quick hack... Any reason why you don't want to just edit the project file?

Comment: I had 50+ projects with Code Contracts enabled, and this was the only way to quickly disable it on my local PC. Modifying all of this projects in all configurations and in several branches was a pain.

Comment: [Fair enough.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to set this via the VisualStudio GUI (there might well be none), but you should be able to just edit your .csproj/.vcproj file to add that property to the appropriate configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    ...
    ...etc
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DestServer>\myserver\final-dest</DestServer>   <!-- <<<<< HERE <<<<< -->
    ...
```

Visual Studio will preserve this even if you edit other properties via the GUI (at least it *tends to*...)

Comment: So, is there a way to then specify multiple property groups and then select on property group based on the active build configuration?

Comment: @AffableGeek There will already be one property group per Platform/Configuration combination, so you can just insert your property where relevant. Alternatively, to avoid repeating yourself, you can create a completely separate PropertyGroup with exactly the condition you require, like `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' "`